# How do I disallow search robots from www.example.com and exsample.com

Tags: redirect, robots.txt

I would like to know if it is possible to block all robots from my site. I get some trouble because I redirect exsample.com to www.exsample.com. The robots.txt checker tools says I don't have a robots.txt file on exsample.com but have it on www.exsample.com.

Hope someone can help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a text file named robots.txt and in this file you write the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and put it in your www folder or public_html folder

this would ask all the search engines to disallow all content of the website but not all the search engines would obbay to this protocol, but the most important search engines would read it and do as you asked

Comment: Haha I had it outside my public_folder... Fail... Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Robots.txt works per host.

So if you want to block URLs on `http://www.example.com`, the robots.txt must be accessible at `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`.

Note that the subdomain matters, so you can’t block URLs on `http://example.com` with a robots.txt only available on `http://www.example.com/robots.txt`.